# selenium 3 AngularJS single select cannot be selected with what worked in selenium 2.53

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, angular

[domImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7HJs.png)

I have an AngularJS application we are testing. When using selenium 2.53 the below code worked. When I switched over to selenium 3. This code no longer worked. I tried using the different selectby item value, visibletext without any success. Then I tried using the selenium recorder to see what I could get back that may be useful. I tried the below which was created by the recorder and made changes for it to work in my existing code without success also

```
//Dropdown Single Select
public static WebElement networkCreateTypeDropDown(WebDriver driver) {
    element = driver.findElement(_networkCreateNetworkType);
    log.info("Network Profiles Network Type drop-down element found");
    return element;
}

public static void selectNetworkCreateTypeDropDown(WebDriver driver, int networkType) throws InterruptedException {
    element = networkCreateTypeDropDown(driver);
    Select drop = new Select(element);
    drop.selectByIndex(networkType);


driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"string:Wifi\"]")).click();
    log.info("Network Profiles Network Type drop-down value added" +   networkType);
}
```

Below is the code from the dom for your review. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
<select id="sel_networktype" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" value="" ng-selected="true" ng-options="n for n in networkTypes" ng-required="true" name="networkType" ng-model="networkprofile.networkType" selected="selected" required="required">
<option value="?" selected="selected"/>

<option label="None" value="string:None">None</option>

<option label="Wifi" value="string:Wifi">Wifi</option>

<option label="Cellular" value="string:Cellular">Cellular</option>

</select>
```

This is the selenium recorder code i mentioned.

```
@Test public void testDropDownJavaTestNG3() throws Exception { 
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/sx200/angapp/ang.xhtml#/networkprofile"); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn_create")).click(); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("networkprofileName")).clear(); 
    driver.findElement(By.id("networkprofileName")).sendKeys("To‌​talTrax"); 
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_networktype"))).selectB‌​yVisibleText("Wifi")‌​; 
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"string:Wif‌​i\"]")).click(); 
}
```

Comment: I see this is your first question on StackOverflow, welcome! To help other help you please describe your question more clearly and not just in the title.

Comment: ​I have an agularjs application we are testing. When using selenium 2.53 the below code worked.

When I switched over to selenium 3. This code no longer worked. I tried using the different selectby item value, visibletext without any success.

Then I tried using the selenium recorder to see what I could get back that may be useful. I tried the below which was created by the recorder and made changes for it to work in my existing code without success also.

Comment: This is the selenium recorder code i mentioned.   @Test
  public void testDropDownJavaTestNG3() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/sx200/angapp/ang.xhtml#/networkprofile");
    driver.findElement(By.id("btn_create")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("networkprofileName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("networkprofileName")).sendKeys("TotalTrax");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel_networktype"))).selectByVisibleText("Wifi");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("option[value=\"string:Wifi\"]")).click();
  }

Answer (score 1):

I was able to correct this issue by updating to the latest version of FireFox. At this time it is 50.1.0. With the initial release of Selenium 3.0 I upgraded to the latest release at that time. But a new release is now available. Not having the newest release of FireFox was causing the problem.